# LLVM scheduling to prevent data hazards

Tags: dependencies, llvm, scheduling

I'm trying to add scheduling to my backend in llvm to prevent data hazards. The backend is very similar to microblaze but with a lot of differences such as multiple delay slots for branching delays. Currently, each time llvm compiles code I always find data hazards especially for load and store instructions.
I've looked at PPC and ARM backend scheduling but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it so I would like to make my own instead.
I'd like to know how to get a list of the compiled instructions from llvm during the compilation process to sort the instructions and check for dependencies based on registers used.

I'm currently clueless on this since I'm not a skilled C++ programmer. The CPU is pipelined and only has control hazards (branching) and data hazards.
The CPU has 5 stages in pipeline but only instructions in stage 3 and 5 are able to use data from stage 1.
I've setting latencies for my backend and it doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should reinvent the wheel and write your side scheduler. You need to add the HazardRecognizer in your backend. This way LLVM's scheduler will know about possible hazards and will try to avoid them. PPC backend is probably the best example of such scheduling.

Comment: PPC's hazard scheduling includes a lot more than what my backend will need. My backend will not have structural hazards and i dont fully understand what isSingle and isFirst is used for exactly. Theres also the issue of properly sorting the code and data hazards for instructions that are placed within a branch's delay slot. A branch delay slot fits 3 instructions.
I'd also like to know how to sort the code after the scheduling. Instead of something like: brid (...),nop,swi,swi i would prefer brid(...),swi,swi,nop.
Thanks